# masking a dataframe to convert strings to datetimes is turning some entries to NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mask

I have a dataframe something like this:

```
Index Hour  type    Horizon      Day    BZ  Value   
0      1    ND       D-2    17-12-2022  FI  7258    
1      1    ND       D-1    16-12-2022  FI  3702    
2      1    ND       D-1    15-12-2022  FI  3702    
3      1    ND       D-1    14-12-2022  FI  3702    
4      1    ND       D-1    13-12-2022  FI  3702    
5      1    ND       D-1    10-12-2022  FI  3702    
6      1    Selected               7    FI  4885
```

I tried masking it, like you can see in the code below, then using that mask to convert entries in another column into datetimes but it is also selecting entries for which the mask condition is false and converting them into 'NaT'. I have no idea why.

```
mask = df_long['type'] == 'ND'
df_long['Day2']= pd.to_datetime(df_long['Day'][mask],format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Like so:

```
Index Hour  type    Horizon      Day    BZ  Value   Day2
0      1    ND       D-2    17-12-2022  FI  7258    2022-12-17 00:00:00
1      1    ND       D-1    16-12-2022  FI  3702    2022-12-16 00:00:00
2      1    ND       D-1    15-12-2022  FI  3702    2022-12-15 00:00:00
3      1    ND       D-1    14-12-2022  FI  3702    2022-12-14 00:00:00
4      1    ND       D-1    13-12-2022  FI  3702    2022-12-13 00:00:00
5      1    ND       D-1    10-12-2022  FI  3702    2022-12-10 00:00:00
6      1    Selected               7    FI  4885    NaT
```

I would like them to stay as they are.

Comment: If you have a column with datetimes, it doesn't really make sense to have other types (such as integers). You **can** do it, but this would force an object dtype.

Comment: Is there a way to use the hour column entry as the time in the datetime column?

Comment: yes: `pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])+pd.to_timedelta(df['Hour'], unit='H')`. Or `pd.to_datetime(df['Day']+df['Hour'].astype(str), format='%d-%m-%Y%H')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, if you have a column with datetimes, it doesn't really make sense to have other types (such as integers).

You can do it if you really need to, but this would force an object dtype:

```
df_long['Day2'] = df_long['Day'].mask(mask, pd.to_datetime(df_long['Day'].where(mask), format='%d-%m-%Y').astype(object))
```

Output:

```
   Index  Hour      type Horizon         Day  BZ  Value                 Day2
0      0     1        ND     D-2  17-12-2022  FI   7258  2022-12-17 00:00:00
1      1     1        ND     D-1  16-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-16 00:00:00
2      2     1        ND     D-1  15-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-15 00:00:00
3      3     1        ND     D-1  14-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-14 00:00:00
4      4     1        ND     D-1  13-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-13 00:00:00
5      5     1        ND     D-1  10-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-10 00:00:00
6      6     1  Selected     NaN           7  FI   4885                    7
```

dtypes:

```
df_long.dtypes

Index       int64
Hour        int64
type       object
Horizon    object
Day        object
BZ         object
Value       int64
Day2       object  # not datetime64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to mask anything, just use `errors=coerce`:

```
df['Day2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'], dayfirst=True, errors='coerce').fillna(df['Day'])
print(df)

# Output
   Hour      type Horizon         Day  BZ  Value                 Day2
0     1        ND     D-2  17-12-2022  FI   7258  2022-12-17 00:00:00
1     1        ND     D-1  16-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-16 00:00:00
2     1        ND     D-1  15-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-15 00:00:00
3     1        ND     D-1  14-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-14 00:00:00
4     1        ND     D-1  13-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-13 00:00:00
5     1        ND     D-1  10-12-2022  FI   3702  2022-12-10 00:00:00
6     1  Selected                   7  FI   4885                    7
```

Or use `where`:

```
df['Day2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'].where(df['type']=='ND'), dayfirst=True).fillna(df['Day'])
```